# I need send value in tap - convert Observable<Void> to Observable<AnyObject>

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a refactor and i need send value when user tap button

Button

```
var onChange: Observable<Void>? {
        return change?.rx.tap
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .throttle(.milliseconds(300), latest: true, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
 }
```

Cell

```
cell
     .onChangeAddress?
     .map { _ in return CheckoutActions.changeAddress }  <-- need delete this line
     .bind(to: ActionSubject)
     .disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)
```

I don't need map. I thing change Observable in button